# Herbrand in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I was watching some issues such as Logica fuzzy logic and Horn clauses and saw some simple applications examples of them , with **Prolog**.

The reason for this question is because these issues are also among the **Herbrand** theorem which I consider a little more complicated than others, at least for me , and I had difficulty finding an application example related to **Prolog** .

That's why I wanted to provide me some **applicative examples using Prolog** , not so basic (because that generates the Herbrand model , according to the definition , are basic rules and always find this application example when search about Herbrand ) , for exclusive use Herbrand. Thanks

This is a example applicative code in Prolog:

```
p(f(X)):- q(g(X)).
p(f(X)):- p(X).
p(a).
q(b).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A set of clauses has a model **iff** it has a Herbrand model.

To prove that clause `C` is a consequence of clauses `Cs`, simply show that `Cs`∪`~C` is **unsatisfiable**.

This is, in abstract terms, what Prolog does, via a special case of **resolution**: You can regard the execution of a (pure—*what else*) Prolog program as the Prolog engine trying to find a *resolution refutation* of the negated query.

The form of resolution that Prolog implements, **SLD resolution** *with depth-first search*, does not guarantee though that all unsatisfiable clauses are disproved, it is *incomplete*.

In Prolog, procedural properties may impact the derivation of consequences. For example, with your program:

```
?- p(X).
wating...
```

Whereas we simply reorder the clauses as:

```
q(b).
p(a).
p(f(X)):- q(g(X)).
p(f(X)):- p(X).
```

we get:

```
?- p(X).
X = a ;
X = f(a) ;
X = f(f(a)) .
```

Note though that many important declarative properties are indeed **preserved** in the pure and monotonic subset of Prolog. See [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) for more information.